# minikube: failed to start on mac with error E1006

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to setup k8s locally on my own mac, and after installing all the dependencies, I try to run `minikube start`, but get the following error message:

```
  minikube v1.4.0 on Darwin 10.14.6
  Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
  Using the running virtualbox "minikube" VM ...
⌛  Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.0 on Docker 18.09.9 ...
E1006 09:57:30.975647   22071 cache_images.go:79] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.16.0 -> /Users/chrisbao/.minikube/cache/images/k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver_v1.16.0 failed: fetching image: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp [2404:6800:4008:c04::52]:443: i/o timeout
E1006 09:57:30.976341   22071 cache_images.go:79] CacheImage gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v1.8.1 -> /Users/chrisbao/.minikube/cache/images/gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner_v1.8.1 failed: fetching image: Get https://gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp [2404:6800:4008:c00::52]:443: i/o timeout
```

and `minikube status` command returns the following status info:

```
host: Running
kubelet:
apiserver: Stopped
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.100
```

so how to debug and fix it? what's the potential reason?

Comment: Did you install kubectl ?

Comment: sure. kubectl is installed.

Comment: `kubectl cluster-info` what is output ?

Comment: `Error in configuration:
* unable to read client-cert /Users/chrisbao/.minikube/client.crt for minikube due to open /Users/chrisbao/.minikube/client.crt: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> E1006 09:57:30.975647   22071 cache_images.go:79] CacheImage k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.16.0 -> /Users/chrisbao/.minikube/cache/images/k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver_v1.16.0 failed: fetching image: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp [2404:6800:4008:c04::52]:443: i/o timeout

Looks like you aren't able to pull the k8s api server image from GCR. You can try use one of the available image mirrors by using the `--image-repository` or `--image-mirror-country` flags. E.g., if you are based in China, you can start minikube with:

```
minikube start --image-mirror-country=cn
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a connection timeout when trying to pull images.

"Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp [2404:6800:4008:c04::52]:443: i/o timeout"

Can you confirm that you're able to access the internet from within your minikube VM?

`minikube ssh` 
`ping google.com`

you should see something like 
[image]